# Laravel 5.1 I created layout and view for action, but if load page 500 Error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

My view (template) @extends on first line:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
<p>This is my body content.</p>
@stop
```

My layout :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hello!!!</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div>

    @yield('content')

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

If load page header (Status Code:500 Internal Server Error)

Comment: 500 errors typically generate an error in the logs. Did you check them to see what it says?

Comment: Copy+pasted your code. Works pretty well. Did you set the route for the view correctly in `app/Http/routes.php`?

Comment: Yes , routes.php get('/',['as'=>'employees','uses'=>'EmployeesController@index']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better if you turn on debugging and post the error log along..

And this should work usually..and make sure your blade files are on root of views folder .

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
<p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

layout.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello!!!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    @yield('content')
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

--Use this on Routes--

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
```

Comment: the problem was in access rights to laravel.log. thanks to all